# How to concatenate a coo_matrix with a column numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a `coo_matrix` `a` with shape `(40106, 2048)` and a column numpy array `b` with shape `(40106,)`.

What I want to do is to simply concatenate the matrix and the array (i.e. the resulting data structure will have shape `(40106, 2049)` ). 
I've tried to use `hstack` as shown below

```
concat = hstack([a, b])
```

but I get the following error:

```
File "/Users/usr/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py", line 464, in hstack
    return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
File "/Users/usr/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py", line 581, in bmat
    'row dimensions' % i)
ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions
```

I don't quite get why the dimensions do not match since both `a` and `b` have the same number of rows.

Comment: I assume that's `sparse.hstack`.  Your `b` when converted to a matrix will be (1,40106).  Try turning it into a correct sparse matrix before passing it to `hstack`.  `hstack` passes the job to `bmat`, which ends up joining the `coo` attributes of all the input matrices, thus making a new matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that's `sparse.hstack`. Your `b` when converted to a matrix will be `(1,40106)`. Try turning it into a correct sparse matrix before passing it to `hstack`. `hstack` passes the job to `bmat`, which ends up joining the `coo` attributes of all the input matrices, thus making a new matrix

```
In [66]: from scipy import sparse
In [67]: A = sparse.coo_matrix(np.eye(3))
In [68]: b = np.ones(3)
In [69]: sparse.hstack((A,b))
....
ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions
In [70]: B=sparse.coo_matrix(b)
In [71]: B
Out[71]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [72]: sparse.hstack((A,B.T))
Out[72]: 
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [73]: _.A
Out[73]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.]])
```

this also works (as in Divakar's answer):

```
In [74]: sparse.hstack((A,b[:,None]))
Out[74]: 
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

My `hastack` does:

```
return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
```

So a direct call bmat also works

```
In [93]: sparse.bmat([[A, B.T]])
Out[93]: 
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

`sparse.bmat([A, B.T])` produces your `blocks must be 2d` error.

Comment: With both methods I get a `ValueError: blocks must be 2-D` error.

Comment: I get that error if I use `sparse.hstack([[A, B.T]])`.  `sparse.bmat([[A, B.T]])` also works. I'm using 0.18.1 scipy.  There may be a version error in how `hstack` converts its inputs to `bmat's`.

Comment: I am also using 0.18.1 scipy. 
Now `sparse.bmat([[A, B.T]])` gives a `TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('float64'), dtype('<U22'))`

Comment: I've managed to fix the last issue. Your methods work just fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the second array, which is `1D` to `2D` and use then `hstack` -

```
hstack([A,B[:,None]])
```

Sample run -

```
In [86]: from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix, hstack

# Sample inputs as a coo_matrix and an array
In [87]: A = coo_matrix([[1, 2, 0], [3, 0, 4]])
    ...: B = np.array([5, 6])
    ...: 

# Use proposed solution
In [88]: out = hstack([A,B[:,None]])

# Print the dense version to visually verify
In [89]: out.toarray()
Out[89]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 5],
       [3, 0, 4, 6]])
```

Comment: Now the shape of the numpy array is `(40106, 1)` but I get the following error: `ValueError: blocks must be 2-D`

Comment: @Old-school Are you using `hstack` from `from scipy.sparse import hstack`?

Comment: Yes, I am using the `hstack` from `from scipy.sparse import hstack`